# How to increase print quality with PrintForm in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6

I want to print the windows form,then i used two methods,

1.Using visual basic power pack tool call `"PrintForm"`

```
 private void btnPriint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printForm1.Print();
        }
```

2.Used `gdi32.dll` with [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Function

but both these method get low quality of print like as a bellow picture.

[image]

But the thing is i'll do it `VB6` and it will print correctly with clear print

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Me.PrintForm
End Sub
```

[image]

How to increase that quality of print ?
(I am using visual studio 2008 SP1 with windows 7 ultimate)

Comment: looks like you're printing IMAGES of your form elements. given your average desktop screen has at best 100dpi, and you're probably targeting a printer that's at least 300dpi, you're always going to get crappy quality. that means not using a screen-rendered print source.

Comment: @Elshan Is it winforms?

Comment: @Elshan : have you tried printdocument ?

Comment: Get a "retina" display to make this less of a problem ;)  But yes, nothing pretty about a print-out where every source pixel got turned into a 6x6 blob.  Growing longer arms is the unpractical solution.  Render with e.Graphics inside PrintDocument.PrintPage to make it look pretty.  Nobody has a use for a paper button.

Comment: It looks like one of them is not DPI aware and you have large fonts set, it's scaling the contents. Did you get the images using normal screenshot or printing to a PDF and capturing from that?

Comment: Oh, and printing the form is the very lazy way to do this. A better method is using normal print operations to layout text and images to the printer. This gives you infinitly more control over the final output.

Answer (score 1):

You can create bitmap image to render pixels in a form:

```
// Assuming this code is within the form code-behind,
// so this is instance of Form class.
using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
{
   this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
   bmp.Save("formScreenshot.bmp"); //or change another format.
}
```

To keep this clean, you can create extension method. For example:

```
public static class FormExtentions
{
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap TakeScreenshot(this Form form)
    {
        if (form == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("form");

        form.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));

        return bmp;
    }

    public static void SaveScreenshot(this Form form, string filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        if (form == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("form");
        if (filename == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");
        if (format == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("format");

        using (var bmp = form.TakeScreenshot())
        {
            bmp.Save(filename, format);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage inside form's code-behind:

```
this.SaveScreenshot("formScreenshot.png",
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); //or other formats
```

**Note:** [`DrawToBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) will draw only what is on screen.

**Edit:** while image in OP is `png` you can use: `bmp.Save("formScreenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: @Elshan Do you want to reduce code? If so you could create extension method.

Comment: How to get print preview of that image ?

Comment: @Elshan You've got two options: 1. load saved image and use it to create print preview. 2. instead of saving image on hard-drive (that I've done just for demonstration) don't dispose it (i.e. remove using) and use in-memory image data to do what you want. _Note:_ don't forget to dispose bitmap when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @Elshan Updated answer to make it more comfortable working with these extension methods.